# how to create stored procedure with parameters of complex datatypes

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am about to create a  SQL Server stored procedure to insert into 3 tables. For Ex: Registering an user. To register an user the system need entry in 3 tables.

```
Class User
{
UserGeneralDetails details;
UserAccountInformation acountInfo;
UserContactDetails contactInfo

CreateUser()
{
DbModule.CreateUser(this); // this function can further invoke the store proc with User object
}

}
```

Is it possible with stored procedure to receive parameters of complex types.

Comment: Which language - is it dotnet?

Comment: Yes Dot Net and I need to write stor proc at Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Why do you need to pass your data as a complex type? Can't you just pass a list of parameters?

Comment: to make inserts on 3 tables, it require 3* 6 = 18 fields. I already have classes. Hence with some deserialization of  JSON or xml is possible with a builtin in SP, then things would b simple than to pass list of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML datatype for the parameter, or use table-valued parameter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Alright. The table valued parameters found to be easier, which 2008 supports. I found this link very stepwise http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/